# getSelectedDataAsync method Permissions denied on ReadWriteDocument level in manifest

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-js

Working on powerpoint add-in, struck with a permissions problem. Could office add-in cause errors on `getSelectedDataAsync` method call, if I've asked for `ReadWriteDocument` permission level? Calling it like:

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.SlideRange, myCallback)
```

Another thing here, there are times I get error and times add-in works perfectly. Looks like page reload in powerpoint online messes up permissions, because first add-in load works perfectly, and after page reload I' getting errors in callback.

Comment: Can you provide the error message information? Can you provide the code that is calling ```getSelectedDataAsync```?

Comment: @MichaelMainer updated text, but nothing fancy here — just copy-past from docs

Comment: @VictorSuzdalev, how are you getting the addin / manifest into the document?  I know of at least 3 ways:  using a fairly new "Upload My Add-in" option in the insertion dialog), using Visual Studio, or via a finished Store add-in.  I have suspicions that you were using #1, but could you confirm?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky "upload add-in" in pp-online, VS debug on the desktop (no "upload" here)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky could rights for custom-loaded manifest somehow change on page reload, if we speak about pp-online?

Comment: @VictorSuzdalev, and to clarify further, you're only seeing this on PPT online, not desktop, correct?

I investigated the issue yesterday, and we now know what's going on, and how to fix it.  A fix should be on its way fairly soon...

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky I'd check in pp desktop, for now had seen this in pp-online only.
Speaking of fixes, does this affect store-published add-ins? What should I expect for now as base level?

Comment: No, this affects only the *developer scenario* of uploading your add-in manifest in Office online for testing (in both PowerPoint, Excel, etc.).  As I said, we have a fix, so a solution should be on its way.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky I'd mark this as an answer if you put it there ;-) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the developer manifest upload feature in Office Online, where a page refresh would cause this error to be returned from Office.js. The fix is now live, please try it again.

Comment: Hello! Could you please take a look at this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016708/get-slide-index-or-visibility-state-of-powerpoint-content-addin-office-js

Comment: Harrison and @MichaelZlatkovsky, thanks a lot for the quick fix! It helped us a lot.