# Get file in Slide Show ("read") mode using Office.js

Tags: powerpoint, office365, office-js

I'm writing a [PowerPoint content addin](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/powerpoint/powerpoint-add-ins) using [Office.js API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office). I need to obtain PPTX file right after user enters Slide Show mode (see bottom of this post for why I need it).

I'm doing this using `Document.getFileAsync` API, as described [in the docs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync). The problem is that it doesn't work in Slide Show mode in PowerPoint Online.

That is, the file gets successfully obtained in all following cases:

- Desktop PowerPoint 2016, Design ("edit") mode;
- Desktop PowerPoint 2016, Slide Show ("read") mode;
- PowerPoint Online, Design ("edit") mode.

However, PowerPoint Online in Slide Show ("read") mode returns an error with message "An internal error has occurred" as a result of `Document.getFileAsync` call.

Is this a bug or intended behavior? What can I do to obtain the file in Slide Show mode in PowerPoint Online?

---

<sub>I need to obtain PPTX file because uncompressing and parsing it seems to be the only way to determine index of the slide that contains the particular addin. See [my other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37016708/804678). I need to do this in Slide Show mode because, in Design mode, user can re-order slides any time, and the addin doesn't know if and when it happened; also, addin might be initialized only in Slide Show mode, e.g. when user opens the presentation and enters Slide Show mode right away.</sub>